# Spring Security intercept except annotated

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-security, annotations

Let's say I have a standard HttpSecurity protected endpoints, like:

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
```

and validators on specific endpoints.

I got a request to make a new validator for most of our endpoints, but instead of adding an annotation everywhere I thought that it could be safer if I secure the endpoints like

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilterBefore(myGenericFilterBean, MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class)
```

(Given that MyGenericFilterBean is something extending GenericFilterBean)

but I want to make it skip this myGenericFilterBean for any endpoint I annotate with an annotation I would create for example @DontCheckMyFilter

Is it even possible without going way too far to make it worth it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option in your case is use an specific `path` to avoid those endpoints, instead of a custom annotation. The reason is Spring filters provide a lot of functionality to work/deal with path and roles mainly.

So if you can change your approach, a possible solution could be:

```
@Component
public class MyGenericFilterBean extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Do here what you need

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  // Method you should overwrite to avoid the execution of this filter   
  @Override
  protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Set<String> avoidFilterForUrls = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("/no-filter/**"));
    AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
    return avoidFilterForUrls.stream().anyMatch(p -> pathMatcher.match(p, request.getServletPath()));
  }

}
```

In the above example, the filter won't be executed (really `doFilterInternal` won't be invoked) for the requests with Urls started with `/no-filter`.

At this point, **you need to take into account** configure your security options correctly. Follow your example:

```
 http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            // List of services do not require authentication
            //.antMatchers(GET, "/no-filter/**").permitAll()
            // Any other request must be authenticated
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(myGenericFilterBean, MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class)
```

Customizing `shouldNotFilter` the filter won't be executed but, taking into account you "are talking" about `MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, probably will be necessary to include those endpoints into the "whitelist" too, as you can see in:

```
// List of services do not require authentication
// Uncomment and customize with your own ones
//.antMatchers(GET, "/no-filter/**").permitAll()
```

Because if you have included a "role based security" or any other one in those endpoints, you need to remove it because Spring still verifies the security for them. I mean, if you don't want to apply `MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter` to those endpoints, no Spring security functionality should be included for them.